# Running code from an imported file in Python

Tags: python, class

I have two files, multitest.py and skiplist.py
We are given skiplist.py as starter code that we cannot edit.

multitest.py is the file I'm supposed to create and borrow the functions from skiplist.py

In the skiplist.py file, we have a method like

```
class SkipList(object):
    def __len__(self):
        """(SkipList) -> int
        Return the number of items in this skip list.
        """
        return self.size
```

In multitest.py, I will have to create my own **len** method, but I am not allowed to access any built-ins.

```
from skiplist import *
class MultiSet(object):
    def __len__(self):
        """(MultiSet) -> int
        Return the number of items in this multiset.
        """
        return SkipList.__len__(self)
```

When running

```
s = MultiSet([])
print(len(s))
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 134, in <module>
File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 56, in __len__
File "/Users/Borna/Documents/CSC148/Assignment/skiplist.py", line 39, in __len__
return self.size
builtins.AttributeError: 'MultiSet' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: technically `object` is a builtin, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your `MultiSet` doesn't inherit from `SkipList` so it should not call any methods of `SkipList` on itself. In this case, as you can see, `SkipList` has a `.size` attribute but `MultiSet` does not.

To fix this, you'll have to either make `MultiSet` extend `SkipList` (`class MultiSet(SkipList)`), or implement `MultiSet.__len__` without using `SkipList` methods directly (e.g. by having `MultiSet` contain an instance of `SkipList` and returning that instance's size).

Comment: I tried inheritance via class MultiSet(SkipList) and got the exact same error.